# Cascade on insert @SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm having some issues due to inexperience in SQL Server.

The issue/problem I'm facing right now is that I have data that needs to be inserted into a master table and as my database scheme is based on the "snowflake-scheme" ..

I have issues understanding what to do when adding data to the master table. My slave tables (I got more than 6 of them), which mostly contain foreign keys should be updated/and if data doesn't exist the id's (which are incremented in the master-table) should be inserted into the slave tables too..

I thought maybe one solution could be using triggers. Can someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. RTFM. And grab some books about data warehouse design. Particular focus on data load scenarios.

The general consensus in non trivial scenarios seems to be from my work experience to NOT do this automatically but through a multi step load process.

You generally load the data into temporary tables (staging tables), then processing runs and fills out the missing information in the related tables FIRST. And then makes the fact table (that is the central table in a snowflake) insert last.

The fundamental problem you have is that it is not possible to insert magic data into a related slave table (as you call it) because the data is not there in the insert statement. I.e. you must have the proper ID in the insert AND you must actually know what other fields to fill out in the slave table. Automatic cascades will not allow the later at all, making it a dead end fundamentally.

And this is no a sql server specific issue. We talk about fundamental concepts of database work here.